# Java fillRect() with TexturePaint is slow

Tags: java, textures, graphics2d, 2d-games

**TexturePaint Problems**

I am currently making a 2D game using texturepaints. One significant problem I encountered was the fact that filling rectangles with the graphics2D setPaint method set to a texture paint is extremely slower than filling a rectangle with a base color. Is there possibly any other way to speed up painting by creating a custom class similar to Texturepaint that paints much faster? At this point I really don't know what to do because my fps is stuck at around 18-23fps.

**EDIT  :**

```
        g2d.setPaint(new TexturePaint(current_paint.getImage(), new Rectangle(CamX, CamY, current_paint.getImage().getWidth(), current_paint.getImage().getHeight())));
        g2d.setClip(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(CamX, CamY).createTransformedShape(paint_regions.get(current_paint)));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, host_frame.getWidth(), host_frame.getHeight());

        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","true");//True or false makes almost no difference.
```

*Note : When commented out fillRectangle() is noticeably expensive.

Comment: I think that switching to OpenGL/Slick2D _could_ solve the problem (but I'm not sure). Can you post sample code?

Comment: Paint what you can to BufferedImages. Show code, preferably a minimal example program.

Comment: @BackSlash I really much rather use Java because I am in the process of becoming a Computer Science major and the starter language is java. I will repost sample in edit.

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder I didn't tell you to switch to another language: OpenGL is also available for Java (lwjgl, jogl), and Slick2D is a java library for 2D programming based on OpenGL :)

Comment: @BackSlash I tried slick2D, LWJGL, and JOGL none are compatible with java Swing which I have implemented into the game. Also I have read a bit on blogs (not the greatest for info) but many seem to agree that java2D has implemented much of the hardware acceleration found in OpenGL pipelines. Java also has the ability to use opengl directly and when toggled it seems to lack any significant change in performance.

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder lwjgl is perfectly usable with Swing (I tried it, so I'm 100% sure). As I said, I ***think*** it can be better, but *I'm not sure*.

Comment: @BackSlash I have never really understood the concept of OpenGL in the firstplace. From what I understand most game developers use it, but not much information is out there on actually how it is developed. Does JOGL and others use pure java in order for hardware acceleration or am I missing something?

Comment: @StoneAgeCoder AFAIK Both JOgl and lwjgl use native interfaces for rendering. So the programmer can use plain java to integrate OpenGL in his application, but the library uses some native functions.

Comment: @BackSlash I just don't understand why oracle could not just do the same thing OpenGL did with hardware acceleration. It has the same access to the native as any other API. But I may think about giving it a try again.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have reduced painting only to what is seen on screen i.e only filling a rectangle of graphics the size of the frame.